# Creating a function a function with an unknown variable type

Tags: function, object, processing

I'm writing a little game in processing and using custom classes to define various objects that appear on the screen.

What I have here is not a problem really, it's just something that's been bugging me.

Take this code:

```
void blitBalckHoles () {  //idealy, it would be nice to have both of these as one function, however I don't know how to make it so that it could accept any variable type as a parameter
  for (BlackHole blackHole : blackHoles) {blackHole.blit();}
}
void blitStars() {
  for (Star star : stars) {star.blit();}
}
```

Basically my question is commented in that first line of code.
Is there anyway I can make one function that blits the parameter to matter what type it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an **interface**.

You would define a **Blittable** interface that contains a blit() function:

```
interface Blittable{
  public void blit();
}
```

You would then create classes **implement** that interface by using the **implements** keyword and implementing the blit() function:

```
class Star implements Blittable{
  public void blit(){
    println("Star blitting.");
  }
}

class BlackHole implements Blittable{
  public void blit(){
    println("Black Hole blitting.");
  }
}
```

Then you could pass around instances of Star and BlackHole as Blittable references. Since any class that implements the Blittable interface must define a blit() function, you can then call the blit() function on any Blittable reference:

```
for(Blittable b : blitters){
   b.blit();
}
```

Putting it all together, it looks something like this:

```
void setup(){

  Star star = new Star();
  BlackHole blackHole = new BlackHole();

  ArrayList<Blittable> blitters = new ArrayList<Blittable>();
  blitters.add(star);
  blitters.add(blackHole);

  for(Blittable b : blitters){
    b.blit();
  }
}

interface Blittable{
  public void blit();
}

class Star implements Blittable{
  public void blit(){
    println("Star blitting.");
  }
}

class BlackHole implements Blittable{
  public void blit(){
    println("Black Hole blitting.");
  }
}
```

Note that you might also just want to use JavaScript mode, since the typing is much less strict that way.

Comment: @The_IT The concept is the same. An interface is just a way to tell the compiler that you know a class has a certain method. Add that interface to any class that you want to pass around as "a class that has this method". If you still can't get it working, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a separate question, and we'll go from there.

Comment: Verry sorry, I started writing a long comment and something happened and only that came out :(. Give me a sec to edit it. Oh it's not letting me now. I'm just gonna delete it and rewrite it.

Comment: Never mind, after a while, I realised my mistake ^_^ Thank you! From when I read your response to when I commented, I knew it should have been something that I could work out my self. (It's just that I come from Python programing where everything is simpler (specifically when it comes to variable types and declarations). lol)